# What is the name of this diagram occurring in topology?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

I found this on the [topology page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Topology.html) of Wolfram Mathworld. What is the name of this kind of diagram and what does it mean?

[image: image of diagram]

Comment: See [fundamental polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_polygon).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The are gluing diagrams for surfaces (plug those words into Google; or read a book like Stillwell's "[Classical topology and combinatorial group theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387979700)").